# Disproving uniform convergence using a sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  with $f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{n}$.

I know it is uniformly convergent, but in my calculation I found that it was not.

Let $x_n= \sqrt[n]{n}$, then $|f_n(x)-f^*(x)|=|(\sqrt[n]{n})^n-0|=|\frac{n}{n}|=1$. Which does not converge to 0 obviously. Where did I make a mistake? I thought I could use the sequence $x_n= \sqrt[n]{n}$ as $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n} = 1$.

When not making using of sequences, I notice quickly that it is uniformly convergent:

$|f_n(x)-f^*(x)|=$$|\frac{x^n}{n}|\leq|\frac{1}{n}| \rightarrow 0 $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use sequence $\sqrt[n]{n}$ as it is not in domain of your function, and in definition of uniform convergence there is "for all $\varepsilon$ for all $x$ **in domain** ...".